# DAW software that I can share between 2 computers?

Tags: sound-design, mixing, recording, daw

Is there a DAW software I could use with 2 different computers and share it?

I will be doing a project for school but I will be recording instruments at home.

How could I work on the same project at home as well as at school? Maybe something where I just have to log in either at home or at school? Or even if i could just download it onto a USB.

Comment: I use Studio One on two machines.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two aspects to take into consideration to answer your question :

1. Find a DAW software that can be run on both the school's and your
   computer
2. Access to the project file and audio files from both computer

**The first point is the most tricky one**:

Do the school computer and yours run the same OS. If not, is there a DAW software that can run on both ?

Do the school computer and yours have similar hardware performance (RAM, processor, etc.) ? Some DAW software requires powerful units to run flawlessly.

Does the DAW software license allow installation on several PCs ? Does it require a [dongle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongle) that you can easily move from one PC to another ? Does it require third-party software to authorize ? Does it require network access to authorize ?

Does the DAW software requires administrative rights to be installed ? Does your school agree to users installing software on the school's PCs ?

**Moving project from one PC to anther**

Moving a DAW project implies moving the project file itself and the actual audio files.

Online storage: are the school's and your internet bandwidth fit to transfer large files ? What about the school's network policy ?

Movable storage: an external USB disk or USB key should be fine. Storage size to be determined by your project size (one hour of stereo audio files is around 600 MB).

**Summary**

With above points taken into account, potential candidates are (based on the idea that for this project, your budget is limited and you don't want to invest into full commercial licenses, and depending on your actual needs):

[Pro Tools|First](https://www.avid.com/pro-tools-first): WIN/MAC, free plus free online storage.

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/): WIN/MAC/LINUX, free and open-source.

[Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm/): WIN/MAC/LINUX(experimental), full version free for 60 days evaluation.

[Studio One Prime](https://www.presonus.com/products/Studio-One): WIN/MAC, free

[Cubase Elements](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/cubase_elements.html): WIN/MAC, 100 € approx. (as suggested by @rory-alsop).

Comment: I'd include Cubase as well - it works just fine for this purpose.

Comment: Good to know. Given the fact that it seems to be a one time project, I have focused on free (as in free beer) software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ableton Live for sure. Project files can be stored in dropbox or other cloud storage, you can add a folder in Ableton Live for easier access.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is you save all your project data at some location available at both locations (a cloud storage as advised above, or a USB drive, or smth.) "Project data" here includes samples, presets, tracks, sequences etc. As an example if you use software that provides basic set of builtins (FL Studio, LMMS, you name it) and you don't use anything other than those builtins then you whole project is contained in a single file.

As an extreme case, use a public service with version control system (gitlab.org, one instance). <_<

Answer (score -1):

There are probably a lot but I know Pro Tools for sure

Comment: Cubase, if you carry the dongle with you. Logic, as it is registered to your Apple ID. That pretty much covers the major bases.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to try bitwig studio or ableton.
both support network link.